# save float variable on python 3

Tags: python, floating-point, save

How can I save floating variables in python 3?,

```
a = 1.03664
b = 2.0367

f = open('file.txt','wb')

f.write("%5.2f\n" % (a, b))
```

or

```
f.write("{} {}\n".format(a, b))
```

but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
a = 1.03664
b = 2.0367

f = open('file.txt','w')

f.write("%5.2f %5.2f\n" % (a, b))
```